# Windows Batch File - Wait until a dialog is closed

Tags: windows, batch-file

Below is a snippet from a batch script I've been working on which runs at startup (or initial login, as the case may be). Part of the script relies on files which are stored on an encrypted flash drive.

I'd like the script to wait until the user has entered the encryption password and closed the dialog window before it continues.

My current attempt involves looking for a window with the title "Enter External Medial Password" (see screenshot) and looping continuously until that window no longer exists.

The trouble is TASKLIST can't seem to find this window by its title, and I haven't been able to figure out why not. 
If I change the `/FI` parameter to something like `"WINDOWTITLE eq Untitled - Notepad"` and run the script again, the loop is happy to continue as long as I have a new Notepad document open (so I know that at least that part works as intended).

```
:DDP
TASKLIST /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Enter External Media Password" | FINDSTR /C:"No tasks" > NUL
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ( GOTO :DDP )
```

[image]

FWIW, in my digging for a solution I checked the parent process for this password prompt for open windows via `TASKLIST /V /FI "IMAGENAME eq EmsServiceHelper.exe"`, which shows a window title of `EMS Message Dialog`. *However* even using this window title in my filter still doesn't work. Also, TASKLIST returns this window title regardless of whether or not the password prompt is open...so that's probably not it.

Any input helps! Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `tasklist /v >filename1` when the window you want is open, then again (using a different file) when it's closed. `fc filename1 filename2` will provide any differences between the two. If `tasklist` is applicable for your purpose, the difference report should tell you how.

Comment: I'm afraid I've already tried that. `fc` has failed to find any differences because the parent process of that dialog window remains active even once the window has closed. So far I have been completely unable to find any trace of a process that is unique to this dialog window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I was able to find a workaround for my issue by instead using:

```
:DDP
TYPE header.txt 2>NUL >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ( GOTO :DDP )
```

What happens now is the script will attempt to `TYPE` the contents of `header.txt` which is located on the encrypted volume. The command will fail with `Access is denied` (and error level 1) as long as the volume is still encrypted, and continue the loop.

Once the user enters the correct password, the file is decrypted and the command executes successfully which breaks the loop and allows the script to continue.

This isn't a true 'solution' for the exact problem, but it is certainly a serviceable workaround and behaves as desired.

For completness' sake, 2>NUL prevents `Access is denied` from being printed to the console repeatedly while in the loop, and >NUL prevents the contents of `header.txt` from being printed once file access has been granted.

Comment: recommendation: never build a loop without some idle time to reduce CPU-load. (a `timeout 1' should be enough)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Stephan! I'll go ahead and add a brief timeout.

The code now reads:
`TIMEOUT /T 1 > NUL`
`TYPE header.txt 2>NUL >NUL`
`IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ( GOTO :DDP )`

*multiple edits for typos and general stupidity*